# Wrong name format. Got uploads\385757.jpg ; should be <app>.<model>/<content_field>/<mimetype_field>/<filename_field>/<filename>

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with my django project

I have a form where I need load the next fields:
Driver Carnet Number
Driver Name
Driver photo

But when i load the image I have the problem, and watched the django documentation and I couldn't solve it.

My model class is the next

```
class Conductor(models.Model):
    ci = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
    nombre_apellido = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=False)
    #para la imagen
    imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads')
```

My form class

```
class CrearConductorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #user = kwargs.pop('alloweduser', None)
        super(CrearConductorForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs['autocomplete'] = 'off'
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'm-1 col-md-3 create-label'
        self.helper.field_class = 'm-1 col-md-6'

    class Meta:
        model = Conductor
        fields = ['ci', 'nombre_apellido', 'imagen']
        labels = {
            'ci': ('Cédula de Identidad '),
            'nombre_apellido': ('Nombre y Apellido '),
            'imagen' : ('Foto del conductor'),
        }
```

My view function

```
def crear_conductor(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CrearConductorForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('mantenimiento:ListaConductores'))
    else:
        form = CrearConductorForm()
    
    return render(request, 'mantenimiento/CrearConductor.html', {'form' : form})
```

My HTML in the form tag

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    {% csrf_token %}

    <table>
        {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Guardar</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 offset-sm-4">
            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="{% url 'mantenimiento:ListaConductores' %}">Volver</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

My settings

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "uploads")
```

I hope you can help me, regards

Comment: always give slash to upload, write `upload_to="uploads/"`. and also in `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'uploads/"`.

Comment: Didn't work neither, because I tried it

Comment: remove name `uploads` from `MEDIA_ROOT` and give `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')`. Also give `/` in `ImageFiled`.

Comment: Sorry OP, you are doing totally wrong, i looked now, first mistake is you have defined `media` in `STATIC_ROOT`, and in your `MEDIA_ROOT`, you have also not given `)`  at the end.

Comment: I supose that, the previous programer used that dir for the STATIC_ROOT,

Comment: What can I do for solve it?

Comment: We allways use our website dev mode, because is internal web and all day has changes!

Comment: Have you done `commit` and `push` on any platform like GitHub or gitlab etc? If you have done so, then only do changes, otherwise sometimes in django, if we by mistake delete any migration file, then we'll face vast no. of errors one after another, and it's very difficult to debug.

Comment: Yes I have a repository!
I have an idea, but I don't sure, I watched existe a command for copy STATICS to other directory, but I am not sure and I forgot the website where I watched, I am going to search again

Comment: I watched here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/ is not completely copy the previos data, is for that I am not sure if could be a solution